# Unable to see eth0 after ifconfig

Tags: ethernet, centos

Yesterday, I have done some changes in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eht0` in centos 6. I have edited the value of `nm_controlled= "no"` after `"Yes"`.
Now, I am unable to see the "eth0" after doing `ifconfig` and lost internet and no ping .

Answer (score 1):

`nm_controlled="no"` means that, that interface won't be controlled by the Network Manager. So now you may have to start the `network` service.

```
service network start
```

Also to get the service running on boot give the `chkconfig`

```
chkconfig network on
```

Also it would be better to edit the question and tell what you are actually trying to accomplish so that you may get the apt answers.

Comment: Actually,Last day ,I was trying to install the yum on my system,but I got some error.To resolve that error,I have edited the network configuration file as told by some other sites and change the value of NM_controlled=no.

Comment: Yes that was the case in older versions, I guess it was some bug and I hope you are using the latest `CentOS6` and in that case you dont have to worry about NetworkManager and no need to give nm_controlled="no" .

Comment: Thank you!! But Now ,when I am going to change the value of nm_controlled="Yes"as default ,it only let me to change the value of nm_controlled ,but do not allow me to save the configuration file by command :wq! after setting the value of yes.That's exact problem .

Comment: ok, may be permission problem, use `sudo`. I think you should first check `vim` here at [tldp](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_06_02.html).

Comment: Okay..Thanks ...Now I am able to see the my system ip address.

Comment: now I am going to install mysql in my centos ,I get the error given below :

Comment: Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base

Comment: @RohitSingh, well as this is a different issue, you'll have to put up another question and for this question you should mark the answer correct and close the question. This is how stackexchange sites work; you cant mix different issues or topics in one question.

Comment: @RohitSingh, and yes before posting a question I would suggest you should make little research over the internet.